# Link to style.css not working

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am pretty new to web programming and Flask. I'm trying to link a `.css` file to the head of my base.html file. I can render the content of the website but not the styles from the `.css` file. This is my directory:

> app
>
> > templates
> >
> > > base.html
> > >
> > > index.html
> >
> > views.py
>
> static
>
> > style.css

In the head of base.html i wrote:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
</head>
```

I also tried this one:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
```

And also some variations copying the .css file around my directory. Still no formatting on the website.

Some further information: By running the views.py I render the index.html which extends the base.html - I don't know if this might be relevant.

Comment: Tips: Enable debug to see any erros. Try to look at browser console to see what`s erros message

Answer (score 0):

Please try this . It may help
**in .py file**

```
   from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory

    # set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

    @app.route('/static/<path:path>')
    def send_css(path):
        return send_from_directory('static', path)
```

in .html file
**

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../static/style.css">
</head>
```

**

**edit :**

```
<head>
        ...
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../static/style.css">
    </head>
```

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\xyz\\python_test2\\app\\static\\style.css'

Comment: @user1974056 Worked ??

Comment: Could there be a problem with the .css file?

Comment: Check the permission of the static folder

Comment: give permission to all files inside the Static folder

Comment: How do I do that using pycharm on Win ?

Comment: Go to the python_test2 folder in cmd use  chmod -R 0777 ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Clicking on page source it tells me "global name 'static_path' is not defined // Werkzeug Debugger</title>" (I was trying the solution from yash lodha)

Comment: hey add this line to index.html. Instead of base.html . And why did you downvote my answer bro ?

Comment: I did not downvote your answer... Now it says: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\xyz\\python_test2\\app\\static\\style.css' // Werkzeug Debugger</title> in the page source again. I will try to add it to the index.html

Answer (score 0):

please try this and please give path to `static_folder` correct means it must point to the 'static' directory.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder = 'path/to/folder/of/staticfiles')
#in your case it is 'static' directory.
@app.route('/static/<path:path>/<filename>')
@app.route('/static/<filename>')
def send_css(**kwargs):
    filename = kwargs.get('filename')
    path = kwargs.get('path')
    if path:
        return send_from_directory(os.path.join(static_folder,path), filename)
    else:
        return send_from_directory(static_folder, filename)
```

This will also read .css files from any subdirectory of your 'static' directory.

just keep this in your index.html.

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
</head>
```

I hope your are Extending base.html in index.html

and rendering index.html from flask.

And Did you understand what path you have to give in your `static_folder` in  `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder = 'path/to/folder/of/staticfiles')` ????
You have to add path of your directory where .css file is kept means your's path of 'static' folder.

Comment: I tried with '/static' as static_path and {{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }} - unfortunately, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! My directory division was wrong. I put the static folder outside of the app folder - I do not know why but Python could not link outside of the app folder. Thank you for your help, everyone!

Comment: try :app = Flask(__name__, static_folder = os.path.join(os.pardir, 'static')) if it  was just out side your app directory may be it will take path of 'static' folder outside from app. and make sure you import os

Comment: Yes , Directory structure is wrong. but you can give path manually in static_folder = 'c:/path/to/static' or by python 'os' module static_folder = os.join(os.pardir,'static')